# Show category children, one level

Tags: categories

I am coding a pretty complex wordpress site (at least, taxonomically speaking), and i need to display a list of categories, children of a parent category, but I am struggling with getting the code to do this.

I tried doing something like:

```
<?php 
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categories=  get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent=1&child_of='.$cat);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
$mycat .= $category->cat_name;
echo $mycat;
}
?>
```

But i don't seem to get the correct output.

Do you have any idea? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using the parameter parent=1?
If you remove this parameter it should work.

If you want children and grandchildren, you should use:

```
$categories =  get_categories('hide_empty=0&child_of='.$cat);
```

If you want only direct children, you should use:

```
$categories=  get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);
```

Also note that you are echoing $mycat inside the loop, and you are joining the multiple categories in this var, so the categories should appear repeated...

Comment: mmh right... and how would i make it not duplicated?

Comment: just put the echo $mycat outside the loop, so that you're writing the list of categories only in the end